# wysiwyg Editor Not able to show image on Editor Box?

Tags: reactjs

**I am Trying to Show image on my Editor using WYSIWYG Editor able to show text in Editor but not able to show image only showing camera Icon.
here i am trying to convert string to html**

> here is my code -

```
> template:"<p><img src="https://i.imgur.com/RcsU9GA.png"
> alt="undefined" style="float:none;height: undefined;width:
> undefined"/></p>"

useEffect(() => {
    if (props.template) {
      debugger;
      const sampleMarkup = props.template;
      console.log(convertFromHTML(props.template));
      const blocksFromHTML = convertFromHTML(sampleMarkup);
      seteditorState(
        EditorState.createWithContent(
          ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
            blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
            blocksFromHTML.entityMap
          )
        )
      );
    } else {
      seteditorState(EditorState.createEmpty());
    }
  }, [props.template]);
```

Comment: which package are you using for that?

Comment: For Editor i am using react-draft-wysiwyg,

Comment: draft-js for converting html

Comment: Its hard to tell. Add your code [here](https://react.new). Its easy to debug if its hosted somewhere